# How to retrieve data from database and pass it to variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I'm working on a trivia game, and need to update the JavaScript code to retrieve data from a database, and pass the data to variables. But I don't know where to begin with making the change. My best guess would be to implement php code to interact with the database and retrieve the data.

The current iteration of my code uses an internal array to create the variables and values for question elements

```
var questions = [{
                   question: "Which list contains words that are NOT names of shoe types?",
                   choices: [ "A. Oxford, jelly, boat, clogs, stiletto, mary jane",
                              "B. Loafer, gladiator, wedge, mule, platform",
                              "C. Pump, moccasin, wingtip, sneaker, derby, monk",
                              "D. Chalupa, dogler, hamster, croonley, frankfurt",
                            ],
                   correctAnswer: 3
                 } 
                //the array contains ten of these objects
                ];
```

The database the JavaScript code will retreive from is coded as such:

```
Insert into  TriviaQuestions(id,questionNum,question,option1,option2,
                             option3,option4,option5,option6,questionAnswer)
Values('1','1','Which list contains words that are NOT names of shoe types:',
' A. Oxford, jelly, boat, clogs, stiletto, mary jane',
' B. Loafer, gladiator, wedge, mule, platform',
' C. Pump, moccasin, wingtip, sneaker, derby, monk',
' D. Chalupa, dogler, hamster, croonley, frankfurt',
'',
'',
'3')
;
  //there are ten questions like these
```

Comment: You need server-side code and AJAX.

Comment: If you just need the data in javascript at load time (not to retrieve things without refresh), you can just echo php data in javascript portion of code.

Comment: By chance, would you be able to link to an example of a code that is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the major libraries (JQuery) to make an ajax request to a server-side script (written in php, python etc..)
So for example:

```
function send_request(question){
    $.post("ajax.php",{send_question: question},success:function(result){
    question = result.new_question;
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is AJAX.

JavaScript is a client-side technology. That means that whatever it can do, your client can do as well. If you were to give it access directly to your database, your visitors would have direct access to your database, and that is not what you want to happen. You may also want to keep in mind that your visitors can see all of the code that you send in your JavaScript, and can edit it arbitrarily.

Instead, you want to write most of your code, including the database connections, and even the answers to the questions, to be handled on the server, probably in PHP.

AJAX simply means having your JavaScript send a POST request to your PHP to get an update from it so that you can update the live page on the browser.

You should have a PHP script which takes in requests and gives out little bits of data to talk to your JavaScript.

If you want to go a step further, you can set a session variable in the PHP that can hold all of the data for the session. The JavaScript can ask the PHP script to get a new set of questions, and then can ask it to check the answer, etc.

Here's an article that should help you get started:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

This article seems like a good, quick introduction into PHP sessions:

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-sessions.php